# Как распределено присутствие пользователей на ruSO относительно времени суток?

Tags: обсуждение

Имеется ли такая информация, как распределено присутствие пользователей на ruSO относительно времени суток? К примеру, по московскому времени.

Comment: По чату можно [активность](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/22462/stack-overflow--) посмотреть например. Из [DataExplorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) тоже, я думаю, можно что-то вытянуть.

Comment: @alexolut: то, что нужно. Спасибо

Comment: Учтите, что там время по UTC отображается.